# Cloning repository within many directories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git

I have this tree structure:

```
./
../
user1/
user2/
user.../
user20/
```

I want to clone for all developers. Something like:

```
ls | xargs git clone /my/project/repository.git
```

I thought about using find w/ -exec, but I don't know how to list only parents directories using find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find . -type d -maxdepth 0 -exec git clone /my/project/repository.git {}/yourproject/ \;` lists only the first-level directories and runs the clone.